# Update field in SharePoint 2010 list to current user

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow

We have created a list that tracks service tickets.  This ticket has a status field with "Open" and "Closed" as options and then another field called "Closed by" that's linked to people/groups. What I'm looking to accomplish is when a user checks the "closed" button in the status and hits "save", I want to automatically populate the "Closed by" field with that current user.  The closed by user will not always be the same as the "created by" user or even the case owner.  I'm looking to complete this in a workflow, but can't get it to populate the "closed by" field with the user who marked the case closed.

The workflow looks to see if CurrentITem:CaseStatus equals close. If it does,
then Update item in CurrentItem.
Under the CurrentItem menu I'm selecting Closing Owner for the field.
For the value, I've tried [Me] and a few other things without any success.

Any suggestions on how to complete this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the update item activity. You can use following look up

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I generally do this by using the Modified By field and populating that into the "Closed by" field.